# JetBrains Rider equivalent to Visual Studio 'New Solutions Explorer View'

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I have just recently switch to JetBrains Rider from Visual Studio. In visual studio (I believe it's from version 2022), I am able to open a new solution explorer window for each project in a solution (right click the project and select 'New solution explorer window'). Very useful when you have several projects in a solution and want to focus on the projects you are currently working with.

I have been unable to find anything similar in JetBrains Rider. I have googled and not finding anything usual. Just wondering if anyone has been able to do this. Either built into Rider or via a plugin.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER Feature requests should go to JetBrains directly.

Comment: @LexLi Not helpful. I was asking if someone had come across something already, not for a new feature to be created.

Comment: No, this feature does not exist and I'm not aware of any plugin. If you'd like to see it, you should follow Lex Li's recommendation and create a feature request.